# SOLVED How to write a method to sort numbers from an array from low to high

Tags: java, arrays

There's an error in this code:

> ArraySortSearch.java:12: error: incompatible types: int cannot be
>   converted to int[]
>                   int [] mySorted = sort(myNumbers);
>                                         ^ ArraySortSearch.java:56: error: incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int
>                           return a;

I just started learning Java not long ago. This is so difficult:( How do I solve this?

```
//not allowed to use import java.util
public class ArraySortSearch { // shouldn't be changed from here

public static void main(String[] args) {


    int [] myNumbers = {15,12,23,0,10,55,2,78,9,6,1,4,11};

    System.out.println("Looking for numer 55: ");
    System.out.println(find(myNumbers,55));

    System.out.println("Sorted Array:");
    int [] mySorted = sort(myNumbers);

    for(int i = 0; i< mySorted.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(mySorted[i]);

        }

} //to here

    public static int find(int [] a, int number){ //this method works

        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){

            if(a[i]==number){

                return i;

            }

            else{
                continue;
            }
        }

        return -1;

    }


    public static int sort(int [] a){ //this method is the problem

        for(int b=0; b<a.length; b++){

            for(int i =1; i<a.length; i++){

                if(a[b]<a[i]){
                    int temp = a[b];
                    a[b] = a[i];
                    a[i] = temp;
                }

            }

        }
        return a;
    }
```

}

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `public static int sort` should be `public static int[] sort`

Comment: your sort method is saying that it is returning an integer but you're returning an array. Change your method to be `public static int[] sort`

Answer (score 0):

Your return type is an `int` but `a` is an array.  Since you are sorting the array in place, just have a return type of `void` and no need to return anything.

Also, make your outer loop go to `a.length-1` and have your inner loop start at `b+1`.

Comment: Thank you it solved the compiling problem! And thank you for spotting the problem in the loop. This must sound stupid but I'm not quite sure if I got you right.

Comment: public static int[] sort(int [] a){ //this method is the problem
   
   for(int b=0; b<a.length-1; b++){
    
    for(int i =b+1; i<a.length; i++){
     
     if(a[b]<a[i]){
      int temp = a[b];
      a[b] = a[i];
      a[i] = temp;
     }
     
    }
    
   }
   return a;
  }   the output list went from the highest to the lowest